# How can I debug a custom LightDM greeter?

Tags: login, debugging, display, lightdm

I am trying to create my own theme for LightDM greeter, concretely GTK's. I have compiled and installed the tarball, but any time I run `lightdm-gtk-greeter` I get this message:

```
** (lightdm-gtk-greeter:29217): WARNING **: No LIGHTDM_TO_SERVER_FD environment variable
```

...and if I run `lightdm --test-mode`, I only get my usual login screen. File /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf doesn seem to exist, which seems really strange to me.

I am using Trisquel GNU/Linux 7.0.